# Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread "No context holder available for step scope"

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hello we are integrating spring batch in my spring boot project but i am facing with this exception`Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope`

Here my step scope bean config class :

```
@Bean 
@StepScope
public StaxEventItemReader<Document> xmlFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
    StaxEventItemReader<Document> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
    xmlFileReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));
    xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Document");

    Jaxb2Marshaller pimMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    pimMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Document.class);

    xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(pimMarshaller);
    return xmlFileReader;
}
```

My main runnable class is annotated with @EnableBatchProcessing

Comment: Hello, your main runnable or batchConfig is annotated with  @Configuration, @EnableBatchProcessing?

Comment: Main runnable , i tried with both but no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, spring error messages are uninformative. The symptom may be the same, but the root cause unrelated, at least to the typical programmer who is not a guru on spring internals. this may be an FAQ that needs to be turned into a "how to find out why Spring can't find the <adjectives> beans I can see are there"

Comment: @user177800 Also, the bug that the answer linked as duplicate points to has been resolved. It is likely that this user's issue is not related to that answer.

Answer (score -1):

use stepscope as below 
XMl config :

<bean class='org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />

if Java config :
@Bean
 @StepScope